# How to manipulate expressions in matrices using sympy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, matrix, sympy

I'm writing a library, and I can construct expressions using objects from my library.  For example, `x` and `y` are instances from my library, and I can construct expressions like:

```
# below is a simplified version of my class 
class MySymbol(object):
    import random
    _random_value = random.randint(1,4)

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, symbol):
        return MySymbol(self.value + symbol.value)

    def __mul__(self, symbol):
        return MySymbol(self.value * symbol.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def _get_random_value(self):
        return self._random_value

x,y = sympy.symbols('x y')


x = MySymbol(9)
y = MySymbol(3)

import sympy
A = sympy.Matrix([[x,y],[x,y]])
B = sympy.Matrix([[x+y,x*y]])
```

This is also true for matrix operations.  The `sympy.Matrix` class converts these elements to `sympy.core.numbers.Integer`, when I want them to maintain their type `MySymbol`:

```
BA=B*A
print type(BA[0,0])
print type(x*x+y*x+x*x*y) # first element of matrix in *symbolic* form

<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Integer'>
<class '__main__.MySymbol'>
```

Now, because `BA[0,0]` is not of type `MySymbol` anymore, I cannot call the methods I want on it:

```
BA[0,0]._get_random_value()  # DOES NOT WORK 
>> AttributeError: 'Integer' object has no attribute '_get_random_value'


expression = x*x+y*x+x*x*y
expression._get_random_value()   # THIS DOES WORK
>> 4
```

How do I take advantage of matrix multiplication from `sympy.Matrix`, but yet still allow the elements of the matrix to retain their class type of `MySymbol`?  and still allow all of their methods (such as `_get_random_value()`) to be accessible?

Comment: cleaned up the question a bit. hopefully it helps make it more clear

Comment: Is it possible to inherit MySymbol from sympy.core.numbers.Integer?

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining that solution.  Can you post what you're thinking?  Or could we have `MySymbol` inherit `sympy.Matrix`?

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to inherit from Matrix. You want MySymbols to be the elements of a matrix, not matrices themselves.

Comment: I see, trying to how to i figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass from a SymPy class to use it within SymPy. Depending on what your class is doing will tell you what class to subclass, but the most typical superclass is `Expr`. See my answer to a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42119908/161801).

Comment: wow, the timing of these questions is good.  I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: yes, that 's what I said in my comment on the question above ^^  .  not sure to implement this though....

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example of how to use a subclass for this?  @asmeurer