# Why won't sympy take my symbols?

Tags: python, sympy

I have symbols defined as follows:

```
import sympy

class construct(object):   
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, symbol):    
        return construct(self.value+symbol.value)

    def __mul__(self,symbol):
        return construct(self.value*symbol.value)

a = construct(2)
b = construct(10)
```

(the above code is runnable).  Now, when I try to put them in a `sympy` matrix, it raises an error and I can't figure out why:

```
import sympy
A= sympy.Matrix([[a],[b]])


....SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse u'<__main__.construct object at 0x1088a5ad0>'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

I'm not even using strings here at all, so I'm not sure why it's complaining about a parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<__main__.construct object at 0x1088a5ad0>` in the error message is what is returned by the default `construct.__str__()` method. I notice that once that method is overridden with one returning the string representation of `construct.value` then anything that uses `sympy.sympify()` (including `sympy.Matrix()`) accepts it. I don't know that this is how existing custom objects are intended to be converted by SymPy--there might be a more ideal way.

```
import sympy

class construct(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, symbol): 
        return construct(self.value+symbol.value)

    def __mul__(self,symbol):
        return construct(self.value*symbol.value)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

a = construct(2)
b = construct(10)
print(sympy.Matrix([[a],[b]])) # will output 'Matrix([[2], [10]])'
```

Were I to do this only with SymPy classes, I would use the following:

```
import sympy
a,b = sympy.symbols('a b')
a = 2
b = 10
print(sympy.Matrix([[a],[b]])) # will output 'Matrix([[2], [10]])'
```

Comment: okay, I guess it was because I didn't use `__str__` method in my class definition

Comment: @guimption I'm still curious why you would want to have your own `construct` class rather than just use SymPy classes--was there some functionality SymPy is missing?

Comment: it's a simplification of the actual class i have defined

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclasses SymPy's classes to create a new object to use within SymPy. Generally you subclass either `Function` (for defining a function, akin to `sin` or `log`), or `Expr` for general expressions. The class should have an `args` attribute and be recreatable with `obj.func(*obj.args)` (`obj.func` is equal to the objects class by default).

I can't really offer more advice on specifics, as the sample class you gave is really simple, and as @Christopher Chavez has pointed out, you can just use a Symbol. But depending on what you want to do, there are various methods you can override in your subclass. A good reference is to look at the SymPy source code, as all objects that come with SymPy use this model.

Comment: @guimption I have more confidence in this answer than one I provided (which was just a hack based on my suspicion that your error message was indeed from `.__str__()`), though it's probably more work, nor am I familiar enough with SymPy to describe how to apply this answer.

Comment: Yes, I think you're answer won't give me all the functionality I need thanks @chrstphrchvz

Comment: Wait, @asmeurer, is there any reason why you don't want to subclass `Symbol` instead of `Expr`?  I'm just wondering....

Comment: You can subclass Symbol too. Symbol doesn't take any args. It's a little harder because you have to modify `__eq__` and the hash. Since you're example is only a limited version of what you are doing it is hard to say exactly what you should do, but Symbol may be better for your purposes.